# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Publish In IIS 6.2

Tags: asp.net, linq

i am working in asp.net linq.when i publish appication in IIS.it throw object refrence error in  one page.when i run appication in local pc its working.iis version is 6.2

Comment: Check ASP.NET version set for AppPool in IIS.

Comment: Provide the code you have tried, please.

Comment: In this data get after click on a button.when i put alert on starting of the button_click event alert not get but in local pc its working fine